# Print A Matlab Struct to a Text File

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab program which generates a set of very large structs as its output.
The structs are sufficiently large that I would like to be able to print the text representations to a text file for later study.

I.e., the command:

> foo(1)

sends the first of the structs to the screen, but the structure is too large to fit in the scroll window, and the scroll window is a poor tool for looking at such a large block of text, anyway.  I would like to be able to pipe the output of that command directly to a text file.

Unfortunately, fprintf is not defined for some elements in the struct, and so fprintf fails.  Likewise, I believe the WriteStructsToText.m script, which is part of the Psychtoolbox library, also fails.

Is there any way to force Matlab to just dump what it is displaying on the screen directly into a text file?

Comment: Have you considered the diary function? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html

Comment: @johnish - I think that's exactly what I'm looking for.  (Experiment.)  Yes, yes that *is* exactly what I'm looking for.  Convert your comment to an answer, and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`diary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) function is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There's no default Matlab function for saving of struct in a file (not that I'm aware of, at least). But there is [`struct2File`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35421-struct2file) function on *File Exchange*.

Comment: It just works for flat stuctures, with unidimensional doubles and chars

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the [struct2dataset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/struct2dataset.html) command to formatting your result nicely before outputting it on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but IMO, the easiest solution is to use the [`evalc` function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html). See console session below, that fails when trying to print a struct directly using `fprintf`, and also when trying to use the output of `disp`, but succeeds when using `evalc`:

```
>> a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]

a =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6

>> disp(whos('a'))
          name: 'a'
          size: [2 3]
         bytes: 48
         class: 'double'
        global: 0
        sparse: 0
       complex: 0
       nesting: [1×1 struct]
    persistent: 0

>> fprintf('%s\n', whos('a'))
Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'struct' inputs.
 
>> fprintf('%s\n', disp(whos('a')))
Error using disp
Too many output arguments.
 
>> fprintf('%s\n', evalc('disp(whos(''a''))'))
          name: 'a'
          size: [2 3]
         bytes: 48
         class: 'double'
        global: 0
        sparse: 0
       complex: 0
       nesting: [1×1 struct]
    persistent: 0


>>
```

`evalc` was introduced into Matlab before R2006a, so you should have no problems with compatibility.

Just make sure you only ever use the `evalc` function if you can trust whatever will be used as the input; EG if you allow the input to `evalc` to be generated from user input, the user could potentially input malicious code, EG that could run a system command which compromises files on your PC etc. But if you use `evalc` on a hardcoded string, EG in the example above `evalc('disp(whos(''a''))')`, then you should be fine.